# How do I make sure my videos go viral?

Tags: vlogger-go-viral

I want to be the best vlogger and get all the views for my videos. I can't seem to figure out what topics will make my video go viral. I try to guess based on comments, but that doesn't always seem to work.

How can I guarantee my videos will go viral so I will get lots of views?

Just to clarify - this is an incremental about being a vlogger, here's a link to it on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.tapps.vloggergoviral).

Comment: Does this have anything to do with games?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, did you check the tags?  It's about [Vlogger Go Viral](http://tappsgames.com/app/vlogger-go-viral/).

Comment: As @GnomeSlice pointed out, this is about a game - its an incremental where you're a vlogger who wants to make viral videos. :)

Comment: @GnomeSlice Of course I saw the tag, but that tag does not have any description. Ashley also does not mention anything regarding games. Hence why I am asking if this has anything to do with games.

Comment: Also, she is 1) a moderator of *this site*, and 2) has 23.2k reputation, it's fairly safe to assume she knows what she is doing when posting a question =p

Comment: To be fair, a lot of games aren't obviously games from just the questions about them.  If the vlogger-go-viral thing hadn't sounded exactly like free (with pay options) game app, I'd have wondered myself.  See also some of the hacker-experience questions (How do I DDoS someone without getting caught by the FBI?) and even kittens-game (Is it bad if I let all my kittens starve to death?) for some similar situations...

Comment: Added a tag wiki and usage guidance, feel free to approve and/or expand upon my incredibly minimalistic start.

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden Hadn't noticed that she is a moderator actually :p. I understand now, thanks for the elaborations everyone

Comment: Oh gawd, this game hurts my fingers... I vote to close and delete this question for the benefit of mankind...

Comment: @Nelson Good thing we don't close questions based on someone's perception of their quality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple: Listen to the community.

When reading the comments, you can see that people often use hashtags and emojis to show what content they want:

[image: Comment Section]

Go through the comments and try to find the one people comments about the most. In my case, it was cats.

After finding the topic, try making a video about it. It will probably be a viral video (worst case, you get %30 bonus).

[image: Viral Screen]

Enjoy the bonus views!

Comment: Is there a way to make those images smaller in markdown?

Answer (score 0):

I think looking at the comments is hard to keep track of sometimes so I sometimes get a scrap piece of paper and do a tally chart and the one that has five comments first, I post a video about. It doesn't work sometimes, but it does usually.